# Accessing user message list with Gmail API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

So i am trying to make this get request to the GMAIL message endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/test%40email.com/messages?q=from%3Asender%40test.com+is%3Aread&key=MYKEYHERE
```

But I keep getting a 401 error about login.

```
 "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
```

I already authenticated the user with: `var SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/'];`

I  know this is an Auth issue but dont know how to solve it. Am I suppose to autheticate the user ever time I need to use the api? What do I do?

**How can I make this get request from the app that is authroized?**

I have it working in the google testing tool [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it)

*new to oauth2 and appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40705533/2972087
It's a working configuration of Gmail API for Angular2

Answer (score 1):

once you have an access token back from your oauth2 login.  you need to use **access_token** not key.  Key is use for accessing public APIs.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/test%40email.com/messages?q=from%3Asender%40test.com+is%3Aread&access_token=YourAccessTokenHere
```